# Removing child node in a XML file C++

Tags: c++, xml, pugixml

I am using [PugiXml](https://pugixml.org/docs/manual.html#modify.remove) library for XML related operations.

**My XML File:**

```
<CurrentStatus>
    <Time Stamp= "12:30">
        <price>100</price>
        <amount>1</amount>
    </Time>

    <Time Stamp= "14:50">
        <price>10</price>
        <amount>5</amount>
    </Time> 

    <Time Stamp= "16:30">
        <price>10</price>
        <amount>5</amount>
    </Time>     
</CurrentStatus>
```

For testing purpose, I am giving a hard-coded value that I want to delete the node `Time` with attribute `Stamp = 14:50`.

**XML Node Removal Code:** I used this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427435/remove-child-nodes-from-parent-pugixml) as reference to remove a node (name = `Time` and Attribute = `14:50`).

```
for (xml_node child = doc.child("CurrentStatus").first_child(); child; )
{
    xml_node next = child.next_sibling();       
    string attributeValue = child.attribute("Stamp").as_string();

    if (attributeValue == "14:50")
    {
        cout << "delete" << endl;
        child.parent().remove_child(child);
    }

    child = next;
}
```

**Question:** The above code runs without any error. It even enters into the `if-statement` but ***why*** the original XML file remains same after the execution?

**PS:** I am sure that the root node and the XML document is getting read properly in General since I am able to display the XML structure on the console.

Comment: Do you get an error while overwriting the XML file with the new content?

Comment: @king_nak: no, there was no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem was in Saving.

I executed the following save statement after the `if-condition` and it worked.

```
doc.save_file("D:/myfile.xml");
```

Comment: That makes sense. You load a XML file *into memory*, modify the DOM *in memory*, and then have to write the new content *from memory* to the file. That's the common working principle. Changes to you data structures usually aren't automagically written back to the source

Comment: @king_nak: Yes, since it was not mentioned in the documentation as well as in the SO answer so, I missed it.